# MongoDB transactions in .NET in 2010?

Tags: .net, transactions, mongodb, norm

Playing around with MongoDB and NoRM in .NET.

Thing that confused me - there are no transactions
(can't just tell `MongoConnection.Begin/EndTransaction` or something like that).

I want to use Unit of work pattern and rollback changes in case something fails.

Is there still a clean way how to enrich my repository with ITransaction?

Comment: Accepted answer is outdated as MongoDB now supports transactions. you may check the following link where i have shared the code needed for enabling mongoDB transaction https://stackoverflow.com/a/72466573/1951420

Answer (score 30, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't support complex multi-document transactions. If that is something you absolutely need it probably isn't a great fit for you.

In most cases, however, we've found that complex transactions aren't a requirement. All operations in MongoDB are atomic on a single document, and we support nice [update modifiers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating), which make a lot of operations that would need a transaction easy to implement (and fast).

Comment: I didn't get that `update modifiers` part. How exactly can they help? (keep in mind that I'm complete newbie at this) :)

Comment: update modifiers allow you to perform certain complex operations atomically with a single operation - thinks like "increment the value of this field by x" or "add a new value to this array".

Comment: @mdirolf Should one refactor if he gets into a scenario where he is dependent on TRANSACTIONS ?

Comment: This answer is outdated. MongoDB now supports multi-document ACID transactions. https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-multi-document-acid-transactions-general-availability

Answer (score 20):

That is true that MongoDB does't support transaction out of the box, but you can implement optimistic transactions on your own. They fit fine the unit of work. I wrote an java example and some explanation on a [GitHub](https://github.com/rystsov/mongodb-transaction-example) so you can easily repeat in C#.

Comment: This is really good example. What a pity it is not implemented this way inside MongoDB, even as switchable abstraction/plugin.

Comment: If you need transactions in mongodb, you should rethink your software design / architecture

Comment: Not true anymore. MongoDB 4.0 supports multi-document ACID transactions.

Answer (score 7):

As of v4.0, MongoDB supports multi-document ACID transactions. Through snapshot isolation, transactions provide a globally consistent view of data, and enforce all-or-nothing execution to maintain data integrity. For more info, see https://www.mongodb.com/transactions

In 4.2, MongoDB will also support sharded transactions.

In this [blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/multi-document-transactions), I also outline our journey to multi-document ACID transactions, in case if you are interested in the history and our reasoning.

Comment: MongoDB 4.0 RC0 is out - Check it out under Development releases at https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#development

Comment: Transactions have arrived! 4.0 GA is out. https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-multi-document-acid-transactions-general-availability

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB 4.0 will add support for multi-document transactions.

https://www.mongodb.com/transactions

Comment: Instead of just providing the link, please put the key text into your answer.  Otherwise if the link goes down we'll lose the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Some notes for the record.

While MongoDB does not have transaction support, it supports [atomicity on a single document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#how-do-i-do-transactions-and-locking-in-mongodb):

> MongoDB does have support for atomic operations within a single document. Given the possibilities provided by nested documents, this feature provides support for a large number of use-cases.

Also, the manual entry about "[Isolate Sequence of Operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/)" might be interesting. E.g.:

> however, you can isolate a single write operation that affects multiple documents using the isolation operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use instead  MongoDb  TokuMX.

http://www.tokutek.com/products/tokumx-for-mongodb/

> TokuMXTM is an open source, high-performance distribution of MongoDB that has dramatically improved performance and operational efficiency compared to basic MongoDB. TokuMX is a drop-in replacement for MongoDB, and offers 20X performance improvements, 90% reduction in database size, and support for ACID transactions with MVCC.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - this has now changed

```
using (var session = mongoDbContext.MongoDatabase.Client.StartSession())
            {
                var itemAuthRepo = (Repository<ItemAuthorization, ObjectId>)mongoDbContext.ItemAuthorizations;
                var calendarRepo = (Repository<CalendarEvent, ObjectId>)mongoDbContext.Calendars;

                if (itemAuthRepo != null && calendarRepo!=null)
                {
                    session.StartTransaction();

                    try
                    {
                        itemAuthRepo.Collection.InsertOne(session, newItemAuthorization);
                        calendarRepo.Collection.InsertOne(session, cal);
                        session.CommitTransaction();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        session.AbortTransaction();
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("IRepository was not casted to Repository");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are multiple ways to apply Unit of Work pattern for MongoDB depending on the database version.

Until MongoDB 4.0, there was no support for multi-document ACID transactions. Then developers has used "two-phase commit protocol" (single database) and "three-phase commit protocol" (non-blocking on distributed databases) to create their own transaction layer which has provided data consistency **but not** all-or-nothing execution to maintain data integrity. So that way has taken down the performance.

MongoDB 4.0 has added support for multi-document ACID transactions.

Sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_commit_protocol

https://www.mongodb.com/transactions

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB supports transaction from version 4.0 onwards and from version 4.4 it also supports creating collections in transaction

I just enabled and tested transaction in mongoDB using free cluster provided by mongoDB atlas which uses mongoDB version 5.0

Following settings should work for mongoDB version 4.2+, although not tested yet.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <mongodb.version>4.4.0</mongodb.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

MongoConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig
{
    @Bean
    MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory 
    mongoDatabaseFactory)
    {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(mongoDatabaseFactory);
    }
}
```

then add @Transactional on function where you want to enable transaction.

It worked for me !