# Python Eve: Add custom route, changing an object manually

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, flask, eve

I just started using Eve and it's really great for quickly getting a full REST API to run. However, I'm not entirely convinced that REST is perfect in all cases, e.g. I'd like to have a simple upvote route where I can increase the counter of an object. If I manually retrieve the object, increase the counter, and update it, I can easily run into problems with getting out-of-sync. So I'd like to add a simple extra-route, e.g. /resource/upvote that increases the upvote count by one and returns the object.

I don't know how "hacky" this is, so if it's over-the-top please tell me. I don't see a problem with having custom routes for some important tasks that would be too much work to do in a RESTful way. I know I could treat upvotes as its own resource, but hey I thought we're doing MongoDB, so let's not be overly relational.

So here is as far as I got:

```
@app.route('/api/upvote/<type>/<id>')
def upvote(type, id):
    obj = app.data.find_one_raw(type, id)
    obj['score'] += 1
```

- **Problem #1** `find_one_raw` returns None all the time. I guess I have to convert the id parameter? (I'm using the native MongoDB ObjectId)
- **Problem #2** How to save the object? I don't see a handy easy-to-use method like `save_raw`
- **Problem #3** Can we wrap the whole thing in a transaction or similar to make sure it's thread-safe? (I'm also new to MongoDB as you can tell).

Comment: Im not for sure how to do the custom route, but Eve does have built in Data integrity and concurrency control. http://python-eve.org/features.html#data-integrity-and-concurrency-control  So you would get a failure trying to update (PATCH) a resource that has already been updated.

Answer (score 0):

1:
`type` happens to be python keyword. Do you mean to say something like `resource_type` ?

2: There is `app.data.insert` (to create new) or `app.data.update` (to update existing one)

3: Apparently there are no transactions in mongodb as apparent from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635718/how-to-work-around-the-lack-of-transactions-in-mongodb) thread (As you can tell, I am new to mongodb myself)

Comment: 1. Yeah, but it doesn't matter! You can locally overwrite keywords (not that  recommend doing it).
2. Cool, thanks!
3. I see... Thanks for the link!