# MongoDB C# - How can I update elements in an array

Tags: mongodb

Let's assume this structure

```
class A
{
  string Id;
  int value
  ...
}
```

and

```
class B
{
    int sum;
    List<A> L;
    some stuff
}
```

I have a Mongo table with objects B

What I need to do is the following, in pseudo code:

```
if (any A item of B has Id == XXX)
{
  if (A.value > X)
  {
    B.Sum += A.Value;
    A.Value = 0;
  }
}
```

in one (atomic) operation.

The B.sum += A.Value and the A.Value = 0 need to be atomic.

I have absolutely no clue on how to implement that.

Has anyone done something similar with MongoDB before?

Answer (score 0):

As you probability know Mongo does not have transaction. 
But in your case I think it is easy to work around if you use a noSql approach. All you need to so is have a single table of B object where the A objects are included inside the array:

a B object
    `{ sum: 0, listA: [ {id: A1, value: 1}, {id: A2, value:2 }], some stuff }`

Then you query for A object do:
   `db.B.find({"listA.id":"XXX"})`

You do calculations on B object and then you only need to update one B record - and that is atomic

This is better explained here [How to work around the lack of transactions in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635718/how-to-work-around-the-lack-of-transactions-in-mongodb).

Comment: so, essentially 2 passes? one to insert the object in the list and a second one to update the time?

Comment: Where do you currently store A objects ?

Comment: Look at the top of the post: I have a class B that has a List<A> object in it. Inserting an object in a list inside a record is not a problem at all; the question is how can I get the server to put a timestamp on A before it gets inserted