# Multi-document ACID transactions in Mongoid 7.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid, mongodb4.0

Support for multi-document transactions are released recently with Mongo 4.0. With the release of Mongoid 7.0.1 (Mongo 2.6.1 driver), multi-document transactions seems to be supported on Rails now.

However the documentation website for Mongoid is not updated it seems. How would we go about using this feature?

I have to update 2 documents (one credit and one debit), so both have to pass or both have to fail. Anyone figured out how to make use of the new feature yet?

(I would use the `mongoid7` tag but reputation not sufficient to create)

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635718/how-to-work-around-the-lack-of-transactions-in-mongodb?

Comment: Looks like they are still working on it, see: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4552 (https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/pull/4507). And maybe also https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4516