# Transactions In MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, transactions

I am using a NoSQL database MongoDB  with Java and Spring Data. I am aware that MongoDB only supports transactions for a single document.

I am using Spring Transactions to carry out MongoDB transcations. I am using TransactionTemplate. What should I set in TransactionManager when using TransactionTemplate?

EDIT

I have something like this:

```
<bean id=”txtTemplateBean” class=”org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate”>
<property name=”transactionManager” ref=”txnManagerBean”></property>
```

I need to define txnManagerBean to point to something like DataSourceTransactionManager for a MongoDB database.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Nothing so far. I need a DataSourceTransactionManager or something similar for MongoDB. Google doesn`t return much. Any ideas?

Comment: Please see edit above

Answer (score 6):

Multi-document ACID transactions are now supported in MongoDB 4.0! See https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-multi-document-acid-transactions-general-availability

Comment: Landing... RC0 is out - https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#development

Comment: Transactions have arrived. 4.0 has GA'ed. https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-multi-document-acid-transactions-general-availability

Comment: MongoDB 4.2 now supports distributed transactions in sharded clusters. https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-42-is-now-ga-ready-for-your-production-apps

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB does support transaction-*like* semantics using [two-phase commits](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/).

There is also another [independent effort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12757751/1733060) to support transactions in mongodb using optimistic locking.

Comment: This answer is outdated. MongoDB4.0 now supports ACID transactions.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't support transactions, it only supports atomic operations.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-data-for-atomic-operations/

Here is a post from someone who implemented transactions for MongoDB with optimistic locking:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12757751/1173560

Comment: Not true anymore.