# MongoDB as main datastore, MySQL for transactions only

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design, multiple-databases, database

I'm having difficulty finding good sources of information on how to solve this problem. Most search results, both here on SO and outside, come up MongoDB ***versus*** MySQL rather than MongoDB ***with*** MySQL. Database design isn't really my strongest forte -- I've never deployed any sort of database to production -- and I prefer MongoDB simply because it's so much easier to learn and work with and I got the most familiarity with it. My question is thus, how would I go about setting up this sort of environment where Node.js is the language and I want to use MongoDB as the main database and MySQL just for transactions or specifically, to enforce consistency and data integrity in the MongoDB database?

**EDIT:** Database activity will be 1% transactions for cascade delete operations with the deletes happening infrequently. The other 99% of the time is where I believe MongoDB will be a good fit.

Comment: I discuss transactions in mongodb here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21887489/68567

Comment: I've checked out your link and your solution looks quite clever. But isn't this some sort of hack and using the right tool -- MySQL for the transactions -- the better approach to take?

Comment: You could argue that if you need transactions why split your data store at all?

Comment: Transactions -- cascade deletes -- will only be 1% of database activity, with the deletes happening infrequently. The other 99% of the time is when MongoDB seems a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using the NoSQL engines in MySQL along with the ACID compliant traditional rdbms engine, InnoDB. See http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/guide-to-mysql-and-nosql-delivering-the-best-of-both-worlds/

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 4.0 will address that 1% of scenarios you are discussing here - it will support multi-document ACID transactions, including cascade deletes. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/upcoming/